# Should we expect the same route from iOS, Android, and Javascript?

Tags: here-api

Assuming everything is working online, if given the exact same parameters, should we expect the same route from javascript, iOS, and Android while using the HERE-SDK/API?

The reason I ask is because I see that the SDK's use a built in router, while the api seems to react to a server. So if online, would all 3 of these devices give the same route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. When iOS and Android use the online router, the result is most likely quite close to JS, but not necessarily identical.

Few points:

- Android and iOS uses a different endpoint/protocol than JS (what shouldn't make a big difference if you really use the same route options but no guarantee results are identical)
- Android and iOS might set implicitly (different) default options than JS
- Biggest difference: mapdata/mapversion. The mobile Premium SDK 3.x operates -as you already said- on local mapdata with a local router. Even when connecting online, the online router response will always match the mapversion you have on the phone (otherwise it could not be guaranteed to be rendered correctly and used for TbT voice guidance on the phone). Means, when you use a 3 month old map on your phone, you will get a route response online that matches the 3 month old mapdata, while JS is always on the freshest data (monthly). Even if you take care to update your data on the phone regularly, you only get updates once a quarter on the phone at the moment. And this means, different mapdata might lead to different routes in worst case.

As said before, these are all details why it can't be guaranteed that the results are 100% always the same, but in many cases they are.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks for the reply.